# Ncurses и память (linux, c, valgrind)

Tags: linux, c, linux-mint, ncurses

Если я скомпилирую и запущу подобный код:

```
#include <curses.h>
int main () {
    initscr ();
    endwin ();
    return;
}
```

То valgrind показывает, не нулевое значение параметра stillrichable. В чем дело? Это проблема?

ncurses `6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1` vlagrind `1:3.11.0-1ubuntu4.2`
вывод valgrind

```
==5849== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5849==     in use at exit: 128,342 bytes in 172 blocks
==5849==   total heap usage: 180 allocs, 8 frees, 137,303 bytes allocated
==5849== 
==5849== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5849==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5849==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5849==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5849==    still reachable: 128,342 bytes in 172 blocks
==5849==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5849== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Comment: Укажите версии Valgrind и libncurses. У меня с `ncurses=6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1` и `valgrind=1:3.11.0-1ubuntu4` всё по нулям.

Comment: у меня ncurses 6.0.20150808 и valgrind 3.13.0  - и поведение наблюдается. Скорее всего есть suppress файлы

Comment: ncurses `6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1` vlagrind `1:3.11.0-1ubuntu4.2`